# Why do these piers have a height miss-match?

Tags: bridges

I found this image of 2 piers of a Grider bridge with varying height. By any change could this be part of the design? The bridge is supposed to be a flyover for traffic decongestion.

[image]

Comment: Are the top surfaces level?

Comment: So far it doesn't seem so. Also, why do they need two piers? (I'm not an expert, just curious to know)

Comment: Possibly, it was easier and cheaper to design and build each section with vertical piers and a horizontal deck, rather than make a one-off custom design with a sloping deck.

Answer (score 3):

It could be the tops are at just the same level, only with deeper beams to cover larger spans at the right hand side, except the last beam upfront is not installed yet.

The missing beam and the angle of perspective creates the illusion that the top is stepping down to the left.